# How to fresh install Windows 10 Home but do i need access to administrator email id for reactivation of windows after fresh install?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, fresh-install

I want to fresh ( or clean) install Windows 10 Home.

When I open **Settings>Accoints>Your Info** , there is shown word Adminstrator underneath the a email id.This email id cannot be changed.**The problem is i cannot access this email id and this id is broken**

So my question is if choose to start fresh install from **Windows Security>Device performance and health**, will i need this email id for activation of Windows 10 Home after fresh installation setup is complete.

Is administrator email id needed for reactivation or i can provide another email id after fresh installation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I reinstall windows without reactivating it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1256581/can-i-reinstall-windows-without-reactivating-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a fresh install of Windows 10 (that is, all new) then you get a new User Profile to start. Since the computer is working, then it will activate itself from the Microsoft Licensing Server. You can set up a new account - either a Microsoft Email account (best) or a local account. If the email account you use is not working (password issues) either correct the password (Microsoft Live Website) or use a different email account

Comment: @sub1996 - That question currently cannot be answered due to a lack of details

Comment: The first line ("I wish to do a fresh install") was adequate to resolve it.